# JQuery Syntax Question?

Tags: jquery, html

What does the following JQuery code mean and how would the HTML code look like using the following JQuery code?

Here is the JQuery code.

```
$("div.result").html(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet searches the HTML document for a `<div>` with the class name `result`. If the element is found then the contents of `html` will replace the contents of the found element.

Thus, if `html` is `Hello <strong>World</strong>!` This:

```
<div class="result">Well, <em>hi</em> there.</div>
```

Will be:

```
<div class="result">Hello <strong>World</strong>!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That will throw a error, unless the `html` variable is set elsewhere.

If you are trying to set the HTMLto itself, why? But it would be:

```
$("div.result").html($(this).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

simply it set the innerHTML of all div of class result to the value of html